# Merge [sound] and [audio] tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

[audio](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/audio) - 1338 questions tagged.

[sound](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/sound) - 692 questions tagged.

Both [audio](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/audio) & [sound](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/sound) - [107 questions tagged](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/audio+sound).

What is the difference between those tags?
I think that most of the users (including me) aren't really aware of the difference between those tags.

Should they be merged?

Comment: I'd be pro merging them, yes. Too unspecific anyway.

Comment: @slhck I think so too. `[sound] --> [audio]`, in my opinion.

Comment: Yes, yes... Get +1

Comment: Both the sound and audio tags now have post counts much lower than stated above. Where are they going?

Comment: @Louis Maybe you're looking at the wrong tab - currently, there are 1350 questions tagged with `[audio]` and 699 questions tagged with `[sound]`.

Comment: @tempy oops, yep. That was it.

Comment: @slhck There's also `[music]`, by the way, but it's slightly different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider this [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).

Sorry that we let this sit for so long.